# bash script - why value is set under function and not set outside the function

Tags: linux, bash, function

The following bash script's goal is to read CSV file ( all_words.CSV  ) and print parameters and values but I have very strange problem.

When I run the script all words parameters (`word1-word8`) was printed - until now every thing is fine!When I want to print as `word1=$word1` outside of function then from some reason word1 `not get the value`?

Why all parameters (`word1-word8`) print the values in function, and when I want to print `word1` outside the function then `word1` is without value?

I tried with export command but it doesn’t help as; `export word1=$word1`

Please advice how it can be? What the problem here?

```
 #!/bin/bash

 read_csv ()
  {
  CSV_LINE=2

 vars=()
 c=1
 while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
    if ((c==1)); then
      vars+=("${arr[@]}")
   elif ((c==CSV_LINE)); then
     for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
        declare ${vars[$i]}="${arr[$i]}"
     done
  fi
   ((c++))
  done <  all_words.CSV 

 echo CSV_LINE=$CSV_LINE
 echo word1=$word1
 echo word2=$word2
 echo word3=$word3
 echo word4=$word4
 echo word5=$word5
 echo word6=$word6
 echo word7=$word7
 echo word8=$word8

  }


read_csv

echo word1=$word1
```

.

```
 more all_words.CSV

  word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6,word7,word8
  &^#G TR /erfernfjer *&^NHY " "" ? /  $@H,@Y^%" E "R$%*&*UJ,**U&^#%%@$^&//  \\,^T%!#&^YG.+___KI*&HHTY,%%@$#!%^#&,P/\06E87*UHG11#
 ,edehu234#@!&,~hum&T%6e4
```

example of script output:

```
./readWords_from_csv.bash
CSV_LINE=2
word1=&^#G TR / erfernfjer *&^NHY " "" ? / $@H
word2=@Y^%" E "R$%*&*UJ
word3=**U&^#%%@$^&//\\
word4=^T%!#&^YG.+___KI*&HHTY
word5=%%@$#!%^#&
word6=P/\06E87*UHG11#
word7=edehu234#@!&
word8=~hum&T%6e4

word1=
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and consider cutting down the code in your question so that it only contains the relevant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please advice ...

Better use `printf`:

```
printf -v "${vars[$i]}" "%s" "${arr[$i]}"
```

Although I'd suggest using an associative array instead. It's the more appropriate solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A CSV_VALUES
declare -a CSV_KEYS

function read_csv {
    CSV_VALUES=() CSV_KEYS=()

    local VALUES I

    {
        IFS=, read -ra CSV_KEYS
        IFS=, read -ra VALUES
    } < all_words.csv

    for I in "${!CSV_KEYS[@]}"; do
        CSV_VALUES[${CSV_KEYS[I]}]=${VALUES[I]}
    done
}

read_csv  ## Perhaps pass the filename to read_csv as an argument instead?

# We can do for KEY in "${!CVS_VALUES[@]}" but the order is uncertain.

for KEY in "${CSV_KEYS[@]}"; do
    echo "CSV_VALUES[$KEY]=${CSV_VALUES[$KEY]}"
done
```

Comment: its dosent work , when I do echo $word1 , after the function , then it not print the value

Comment: in your code its not print also the echo $word1 in side the function? why ?

Comment: @maihabunash What exactly doesn't work? When you replaced `declare ${vars[$i]}="${arr[$i]}"` with `printf ...`? Or my code itself? What error messages do you get? Of course I saved the data in CSV_VALUES and optionally saved the keys in CSV_KEYS.

Comment: I need the ability to print the parameters ( word1 - word8 ) , this is my basic question , so I need to do as echo $wordx from any function in  the script

Comment: @maihabunash Well have you tried replacing `declare ${vars[$i]}="${arr[$i]}"` with `printf -v "${vars[$i]}" "%s" "${arr[$i]}"`?

Comment: Also that's the best suggestion I can make with respect to your old code. I can't suggest any better. I find it really wrong storing data on open variables like that. Better use associative arrays as I suggested.

Comment: the problem is that for example when I try to do echo $word1 it not print the value ( inside the function or outside )

Comment: To learn more about associative arrays go here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays

Comment: print command give me this error --> ./readWords_from_csv.bash: line 45: printf: `': not a valid identifier

Comment: @maihabunash Doesn't `declare` share that error message as well when it doesn't recognize a valid variable?

Comment: That clearly shows that a part of your csv file could make your script declare an invalid variable. This is why I'm recommending that you use associative arrays instead. I gave my best attempt to help already. Good luck.

Comment: can you please re-edit my code with all what need to add , so it will be more simple?

Comment: @maihabunash It's hard for me to add more to your code. Like I said I don't recommend the approach you make. I recommend that you give an effort to study the code I suggested. It probably could help you a lot.

Comment: yes but when I run your code I not get get any values ? , example --> CVS_VALUES[word1]=
CVS_VALUES[word2]=
CVS_VALUES[word3]=
CVS_VALUES[word4]=
CVS_VALUES[word5]=
CVS_VALUES[word6]=
CVS_VALUES[word7]=
CVS_VALUES[word8]=

Comment: @maihabunash Can you post samples from your data so I could test the script? It's still blind-coded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57844/discussion-between-maihabunash-and-konsolebox).

Answer (score 5):

`man bash` explains under `declare`:

> When used in a function, `declare` makes NAMEs local, as with the `local` command.

Answer (score 3):

```
    declare -g ${vars[$i]}="${arr[$i]}"
#           ^^
```

Use `declare -g` to declare a variable at global level in a function. From `man bash`:

```
   declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
          [...]  The -g option forces
          variables  to  be  created or modified at the global scope, even
          when declare is executed in a shell function.  It is ignored  in
          all  other cases. [...]
```

---

Here is a simple demonstration of the `-g` flag (works as expected on GNU bash, version 4.2.37):

```
#!/bin/bash

function f() {
    declare -g V
    V="hello"
}

f
echo $V
```

Comment: so I need just to add the line "declare -g ${vars[$i]}="${arr[$i]}"
" in my code - just all??

Comment: I was added this line and I get this error --> ./readWords_from_csv.bash: line 3: declare: -g: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: Just to add that while this could help declare a value to a global variable, it would not help on declaring a variable between functions. Let's say variable A is local to a() and a() calls b(). With `declare -g A=something`, b() won't be able to set a value to A. It would set a value to a global variable A instead.

Comment: And of course it requires Bash 4.2. Prior versions would not work.

Comment: @konsolebox Yes, that right, `declare -g` won't automagiccally promote all the variable with the given name as globals.

Comment: @maihabunash What is you bash version?